# How to collapse tableview with animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with two sections.

```
var categories = ["a", "b", "c"]
var items = ["1" , "2", "3"]//will be different based on category selection
var selectedCategory: String?
```

Initially first section only visible. After the user selects any row in 0th section section 1 will have 3 rows and section 0 will have only selected row.

For ex. if category "b" is selected "a","c" rows should be removed and "1","2","3" rows should be added.

Now if the "b" is deselected "a","c" rows should be added and "1","2","3" rows should be removed.

//UITableViewDataSource

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return selectedCategory == nil ? 1 : 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return section == 0 ? categories.count : items.count
}
```

I've done this using `tableView.reloadData()`. It does't show any animation. I'm trying to achieve this using the following methods

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

**I'm struggling to get indexpaths to insert and delete**

Answer (score 1):

instead of reload whole tableView do this:-

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.top)
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.top)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm struggling to get indexpaths to insert and delete

Comment: can you please show us your code for inserting and deleting?

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal you should maintain a array with all `indexPath` from `cellForRow`. From this array you can get the `indexPath`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `deleteRows` and `insertRows` call in `tableView.beginUpdates` and `tableView.endUpdates`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates?language=objc

Or use `performBatchUpdates:completion:`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates?language=objc

**Edit**

Ok, let me explain some things in detail. :-)

First I think you need to modify `numberOfRowsInSection`, because you said section 0 should show all categories as long as none is selected and after selecting one, it should display only that one row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        // If no category is selected, we display all categories, otherwise only the selected one.
        return selectedCategory == nil ? categories.count : 1
    case 1:
        return items.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

Second, this is an example of how `didSelectRowAt` could look like. I changed `selectedCategory` to `Int?` to store the index of the selected category and not its name.
As you can see, in section 0 the rows that are not the selected category are deleted, while section 1 is added completely, as it did not exist before.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedCategory == nil {
        // Save index on selected category
        selectedCategory = indexPath.row

        // set items array
        …

        // Animate change
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        for (index, _) in categories.enumerated() {
            if index != selectedCategory {
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
            }
        }

        tableView.performBatchUpdates({
            // delete rows from section 0
            tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
            // insert section 1
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .automatic)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm struggling to get indexpaths to insert and delete

Comment: Added a few details to my answer. HTH.